How to find performance bottleneck in SQL Server 2019 when sys.dm_os_wait_stats show the contrary?
There is an on prem SQL Server 2019. It is virtualized with VMware 7.0.3. The database shows a weak performance:

it produces way more deadlocks than a system clone running on a local Docker setup.
The execution of basic SELECT Statements occasionally "hangs", meaning it takes extra seconds to complete though data is already visible.

To identify the bottleneck, a script to insert 10,000 rows into a table is executed on this database, a local Docker database, and a SQL Server RDS at Amazon RDS. sys.dm_os_wait_stats are cleared before the execution, and compared afterwards.
It took 7s to complete the script on the on prem server (the one to investigate), 2s to complete on the AWS RDS, and ~50s on Docker.
However, the sum of wait_time_ms on on prem server is 164,796ms, while it is 6,920,143ms for the AWS RDS. For the Docker setup it is 7,246,454ms.
I/O is no bottleneck on the on prem server, since the numbers for WRITELOG, PAGEIOLATCH_EX, PAGEIOLATCH_SH, IO_COMPLETION, ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION are between 0 and 3ms.
(Reference)
This script is not memory intense so I doubt it is on memory. MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT and RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT block 0ms in total.
For CPU: I don't expect a lack of CPU because these are the only wait types showing waits:
XE_TIMER_EVENT - 10012
REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH - 5012
SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER - 21
Am i wrong?
I got a hint that the VM might be underprovisioned with CPU and that this is not reflected in the wait statistics.
So, here are the questions:

How to test if the server is underprovisioned on VM-level?
Any other ideas on how to identify the bottleneck?

Thanks in advance!

INSERT statements cannot be tuned. you have to note down top bottlenecks and start working on it. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/29/sql-server-ssms-top-queries-by-cpu-and-io/. You have to see the execution plan of these queries to understand the bottlenecks and work on it
